# ImageView loading issue from FilePath in Android (cut off)

Tags: android, xml, imageview, screenshot, filepath

I have a screenshot Image from my file path which I am trying to load into ImageView.
However, the imageView is cut off.

This is how it looks like:

[image: This is how it looks like]

This is how it should be:

[image: This is how it is]

This is my code :

```
// MainActivity.java
//Setting image view from filepath
      File imgFile = new File(arScreenshotPath);
      ImageView myImage = findViewById(R.id.arScreen1);
      if(imgFile.exists()){
        myImage.setImageBitmap(Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(arScreenshotPath, 500, 250));

//        myImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 206, 144, false));
      }else {
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
      }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CostActivity">

    <!-- Ar Screen capture -->
    <!-- Ar Screen capture -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arScreen1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="211dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />


    <!--    Description -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quote2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DESCRIPTION"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/descriptionInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!--    Measurement -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/measurement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MEASUREMENT"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--  Length -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/lengthTextInputLayout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/lengthInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:hint="Length"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <!--    Breadth    -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="X"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/breathTextInputLayout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="179dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/breathInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:hint="Breadth"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/cm"
            style="@style/spinnerItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--    Cost Per Square CM -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cost_per_square_cm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COST PER SQUARE UNIT"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/costTextInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/costInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:hint="$"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!--   Variable -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/variable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VARIABLE (+)"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/variableTextInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/variableInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:hint="$"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried many methods, like reducing the layout weight, but it all does not work.
I suspect that it could be due to the Java Code as well.

Comment: You might want to save your self some time and use a well written images library!
e.g https://square.github.io/picasso/
Also, from your code, I can guess the issue is from myImage.setImageBitmap ... where you're also specifying the width and height of the image! so the xml attribute about the imageView get overwritten by the java code.

Comment: can you show what decodeSampledBitmapFromFile is?

Comment: try, this my solution

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in your ImageView block

`android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

`android:layout_weight="0.2"`

You can change the value of `android:layout_weight`

Comment: i have tried all of the above, but it still doesnt work